# How to launch a python window to a specific screen location with os.system

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system

I need to launch many windows of python terminals from another python terminal.  I do not want to load PyGame or any other module that might add memory or overhead.  I am using OS.   Currently it works great and does exactly what I need to use... os.system and then start and the file path to the .py file.  But I really want to control where these windows open on the screen.  One option is to have it run a batch that has its own code to control the terminal position and then launches the python.  But I would really prefer a way to do this directly from python.  Is there any code that can control the position of the window when using os.system to launch a .py file in a terminal?

Within Windows 10.

Cheers!

Comment: This totally depends on the operating system you are using... Are you on Windows, Linux etc.? 

To give you an example: I'm om Linux and use i3 as a tiling window manager. Any configuration to the placement of my windows is therefore made in configuration files of i3 and has nothing to do with the content that is run.

Comment: on Linux you can also run `gnome-terminal --geometry=WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y -- "python ..."` and it will open `terminal` in position `X,Y` and run directly `python` (without `bash`).

Comment: Sorry windows 10